# Request login data of the native Facebook app on android / ios to navigator

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile

I'm creating a web page in which the user must "Like" a page to be able to join the service.

To check that he does, I need the user to be identified on Facebook. The problem is that if the user opens the link (keep in mind that it's a web service) in the mobile browser, he will have to login again which is an obstacle.

If I could get the account status from the native application, it could solve the problem.

**The concrete question:**

How can you check if the user is identified in the native Facebook APP from the mobile browser ?

If the user is identified in the native APP Facebook then pressing "Like" to LikeBox shouldn't require another identification in the mobile browser.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question ? At the moment, it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: Edit, is it more clear now? Sorry for my bad english :$ Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question to get rid of some of the grammar errors, as well as rephrased a little to make it more comprehensible.